# How to query needed size for output buffer when calling AcceptSecurityContext?

Tags: windows, sspi

I tried usual Windows way, I passed nullptr as output buffer pointer and size 0. `AcceptSecurityContext` fails with error `SEC_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY`. I was expecting to get needed size in `OutSecBuff.cbBuffer` but it is 0. I call it again with huge buffer. Call succeeds but context is invalid an later calls fail.

```
// Query needed buffer size
secStatus = AcceptSecurityContext(&hcred,&hctxt, &InBuffDesc,attr,SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP,
   &hctxt,&OutBuffDesc,&attr,nullptr);

if(SEC_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY == ss)
{
    // Allocate buffer of needed size, big enough
    OutSecBuff.cbBuffer = *pcbOut;
    OutSecBuff.pvBuffer = pOut;
    // Call with buffer of required size
    secStatus = AcceptSecurityContext(&hcred,&hctxt, InBuffDesc,
       attr,SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP,&hctxt,&OutBuffDesc,&attr,nullptr);
}
```

If I preallocate huge buffer, everything works fine.
I would like to dynamically allocate buffer of needed size.

Comment: ASC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY?

Comment: This is true but I wanted to *reuse buffer*. In first call, I would specify size of the existing buffer. If it is not enough, function would return `SEC_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY` and needed buffer size. This is how other Windows API functions work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSAPI takes different approcah. When querying security package `QuerySecurityPackageInfo`, max size of output buffer is returned in field `cbMaxToken`. You allocate buffer once and you can be assured that buffer size will be enough for all requests.